# Upgrade Isolated storage settings from WP8 to WP8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a windows phone 8 app which I want to upgrade to WP8.1 universal app. Isolated Storage is not supported in 8.1, how do I upgrade my isolated settings in such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The __ApplicationSettings file which contains the IsolatedStorageSettings will be located in the local folder of the app when it was updated through the store.
This is not the case when updating the app through Visual Studio, as it seems to have difficulties replacing a Silverlight app with a WinRT app.

You need to deserialize this file to any known objects, and the store the objects someplace else.
The following code will fetch the IsolatedStorageSettings in a WinRT app:

```
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>> GetIsolatedStorageValuesAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var fileStream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("__ApplicationSettings"))
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                {
                    var line = streamReader.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;

                    var knownTypes = line.Split('\0')
                        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                        .Select(Type.GetType)
                        .ToArray();

                    fileStream.Position = line.Length + Environment.NewLine.Length;

                    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (Dictionary<string, object>), knownTypes);

                    return (Dictionary<string, object>) serializer.ReadObject(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            // ignore the FileNotFoundException, unfortunately there is no File.Exists to prevent this
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I have done something similar. thanks for your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

[ApplicationData.LocalSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) -- Gets the application settings container in the local app data store.

NameSpace : `Windows.Storage`

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

// Create a simple setting

localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = "Hello Windows";

// Read data from a simple setting

Object value = localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"];

if (value == null)
{
    // No data
}
else
{
    // Access data in value
}

// Delete a simple setting

localSettings.Values.Remove("exampleSetting");
```

You can read documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361.aspx)

Comment: So using this I could access my WP8 (Silverlight) settings on the new universal wp8.1 app?

Comment: No.. I don't think so, You can use this instead of IsolatedStorageSettings & I have a question for you. How you upgarding your windows phone 8 silverlight app to Universal app... I think you are creating as new project. Am I right...!

Comment: Yes, I will be creating a new project, but when I upload it to store it will appear as upgrade to my existing users and not as fresh install.

Comment: Your users will lose data if you do that. If you want to retain data you need to either store it somewhere online, or you can upgrade to a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app.